# How to fix Command "code-runner.run" not found

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a `test.java` file and also it sends an error `Extension host terminated unexpectedly` then whenever I restart the host the following Command Appear `code-runner.run` not found.

Reinstalled extensions

```
    public static void name(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Hello World

Comment: now the issue is "Extension host terminated unexpectedly" or "code-runner.run not found" ?

Comment: you could refer this:https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/268

Comment: I think "Extension host terminated unexpectedly" is the reason why "code-runner.run not found" is appearing, but still dont know how to fix the extension host

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try deleting the `C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\formulahendry.code-runner-...` folder and installing the extension again.

See [this issue](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/351#issuecomment-416806210) on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

Delete the  complete folder on which you are working currently.And make another with the another name with another file name, and work again, my problem was solved like this.Hope it will help you sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be from the code editor. Try closing your code editor(vscode) & reopen it again.

Comment: Should be a comment because you are only guessing. But hey, you can't post comments, so you should delete this answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).